# How to store the SQL query result using Airflow and use the result in if else condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I was trying to use XCOM but its showing none as the value

```
class DWPostgresReturn(DWPostgresOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        self.log.info('Executing: %s', self.sql)
        hook = DWPostgresHook(postgres_conn_id=self.postgres_conn_id, schema=self.database)
        return hook.get_records(
            self.sql,
            parameters=self.parameters)

with DWDAG(config) as dag:

    t1 = DWPostgresReturn(
       task_id='t1',
       postgres_conn_id='db_conn',
       sql="select output from table",
       config=config,
       start_date = dt.datetime(2020,3,9)

    )

    def get_records(**kwargs):
       ti = kwargs['ti']
       xcom = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='t1')   
       string_to_print = 'Value in xcom is: {}'.format(xcom)
       print(xcom)



    t2 = PythonOperator(
       task_id='records',
       provide_context=True,
       python_callable=get_records,
       config = config,
       start_date = dt.datetime(2020,3,9)


    )

t1 >> t2
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the environment. Was there a stack trace? Without these details nobody is able to help you.

Comment: Below is the log 
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=records
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2020-03-05T11:14:46.675046+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2020-03-05T11:14:46.675046+00:00
[2020-03-09 13:16:28,681] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2020-03-09 13:16:28,681] {demographic1.py:63} INFO - Value in xcom is: None

Comment: What task is putting the value in XCOM for this key?

Answer (score 2):

You can use hooks to get results of sql query and use it as you like. For example with snowflake:

```
dwh_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONNECTION_ID)
query_result = dwh_hook.get_first("""<your query>""")[0]
```